# Prevent Windows to reset keyboard layout after a reboot?

Tags: windows-11, keyboard-layout

Laptop has a different keyboard layout than the external keyboard connected to it.

Basically, every time it's rebooted, the keyboard layout is reverted to laptop's.

So, every time after reboot, I have to do <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to switch to the other layout.

Is there a way to disable that behavior?